# mysql dump best practices for development

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have an application that has a large database that includes, among many other tables, a table called `content` and a table called `users`.

I would like to set up a development environment for this application, however I would like to bring in only some parts of the `content` and `users` tables.

If there are 50,000 rows for each of these tables, I only want to bring over 10 rows so my development environment has at least some data.

What is the best way to create a dump of the database data and structure, while also limiting the size of the dump and the risk of putting sensitive information in a development environment?

Comment: Check these out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135835/limiting-the-number-of-records-from-mysqldump https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734175/script-to-dump-single-record-from-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 10" database
```

**It's an SQL injection:**
The `--where` option is basically appended to a query of the form `SELECT * from table WHERE` , so in this case you get `SELECT * from table WHERE 1 limit 10`. Without the 1, you would have an invalid query. Specifying 1 for a where clause (since 1 is always true) simply selects all records.

Source: [Limiting the number of records from mysqldump?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135900)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to create a dump of the database data and structure, while also limiting the size of the dump and the risk of putting sensitive information in a development environment?

The best way to prevent sensitive data getting into your Development environment is *not to put it there* in the first place.

If you only want ten rows in each table, then write a SQL script to *create* those ten rows.  That way, you have a consistent set of data that you can re-apply repeatably to your development database, any time you like.

If you were to take, say, the "first" ten rows from each table, then

- There there's no guarantee that you'd get the same rows each time ("Rows have *no intrinsic order*"), so any dependent test cases would break,
- You run the risk of pulling across sensitive data.